# where do I see the "Certification Path tab"?

Tags: ssl

I get a message from Symantec saying : NOTE: A restart of the Web site(s) from within IIS may be necessary in order for the changes to take effect. After the installation of your certificate and the Intermediate CAs you should now see four certificates in a chain under Certification Path tab. The first one from the bottom will be your SSL certificate, the next one the secondary intermediate, the third one the primary intermediate and the fourth one the Root CA.

but how do I get into the "Certification Path tab" ?

Answer (score 0):

open that website in a browser...

For example...

https://www.google.co.in/

after hitting enter you will see the lock symbol in address bar before **https**

if you click on that lock symbol you will get certificate information

Goto connection tab...click on certificate information

Then you will get certificate path tab...